# Clicking on a button doesn't trigger the event in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have the following css:

```
.glb-nav-hamburger {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 38px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.glb-nav-hamburger span, .glb-nav-hamburger span:before, .glb-nav-hamburger span:after {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
.glb-nav-hamburger span:before {
    top: -10px;
}
.glb-nav-hamburger span:after {
    bottom: -10px;
}
.glb-nav-hamburger span, .glb-nav-hamburger span:before, .glb-nav-hamburger span:after {
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

and the following html

```
<button class="glb-nav-hamburger"><span></span></button>
```

I have a backbone view with the following event

`"click .glb-nav-hamburger": "showMenu",`

In all other browsers, I can click on any part of the button and get the showMenu function to run; however, in firefox I can only click on a small subsection of the button to get the showMenu function to run. If I click on the center of the button, the showMenu function doesn't run. If I click on the left part of the button, the showMenu function does run.

How can I make it so that in firefox, I can click on any part of the button and the showMenu function will run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving your absolutely positioned button a height & width:

```
.glb-nav-hamburger {
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 25px;
z-index: 1000;
top: 38px;
cursor: pointer;

width: 35px;
height: 35px; /* not sure if this would be the height needed for your button */
}
```